# Inserting strings into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, encoding

I am running into a problem where I think my insert statement in MySQL is messing up the strings that get entered into the database.

I have an insert statement like this in PHP code:

```
$sql = 'insert into my_table ( numeric_id , string_value ) 
        values ( '.$some_number.' , "'.$some_text.'" )';
```

And when later I get the `$some_text` from the database, it messes up strings like 
`don\'t` instead of don't and ads things like `\r\n` to the output.

Any idea why this is happening and what I should change?

Comment: The best would be if you could show both the code you use to insert and output the data, and what exactly the output looks like.

Comment: Just as an aside, your code suffers from a [Bobby Tables attack](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You may have magic quotes enabled.

Comment: @CanSpice quite contrary, it's consequences of this stupid comic.

Comment: Hey guys, I have magic quotes DIS-abled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your code is doing escaping twice.
You just have to find the code that does it second time and  get rid of it.

first of all you have to print out your variables to see it's actual contents.
It's hard as hell to sort out things being blinded and based on assumptions.

Just print out `$some_text` variable before escaping it and see. if it's already escaped - then additional escaping been done somewhere earlier in the code.

Comment: Not until every install of PHP with magic_quotes enabled is nuked from orbit, and then its containing universe is similarly deleted from the metaverse.

Comment: @Col there is no evidence that he's not got magic quotes on and is also escaping input with a separate function call, as I keep telling you. More info from OP required!

Comment: @Andy if he's got magic quotes AND doing escaping twice, then `don't` going to be `don\\\'t`. don't you see it?

Comment: @Col FFS try this: (create tmp table) `insert into test values ('don\\\'t');` and `select * from test;` and you get: `don\'t`. I ran this before answering, did you?

Comment: @Andy that's good of you to make tests. now try to get literal \r\n in the output

Comment: @Col `mysql_real_escape_string('\r\n')` gives `\\r\\n` which when inserted appears in the database as `\r\n` - he would need to use single instead of double quotes to prevent escape characters being interpreted, which neither of us know if he did or not!

Comment: @Andy how come? he is getting his data from the browser. why not to read question?

Comment: @Chris I am just feeling sick when such a relatively easy question gets so much wrong answers.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I hear you.  Hey, its people like you who will make the solution easier to find, thus making stackoverflow more efficient.  No complaints here, as long as you got good reason to downvote!  In this case I can see where your are coming from as \r\n will NOT be caused by the magic quotes.  This was why I deleted my answer :)

Comment: When you say escaping twice, what could it be other than this which I do once: $string_value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['string_value']);

Comment: @Genadinik I think you want to use mysql_real_escape_string() in your insert statement.  Let Col. Shrapnel guide you though, he has already proven himself here I believe.

Comment: @Genadinik I smell some "smart" sanitizing function that's mixing everything: trim, htmlspecialchars, mysql_real_escape_string and such, being applied to all input data somewhere earlier in the code, in a bootstrap-like snippet. You can easily determine direction of your search though - just `echo $_POST['string_value'];` before escaping. if it's clean - additional escaping is below. if it's escaped - then somewhere above.

Comment: So do you mean then that the problem is not on the insert side, but more when I show the entered data in a page?  Also, can it have to do with encoding?

Comment: To show the text I have to do this to avoid showing the \r\n strings:    $text_variable= str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n\r'), '<br />',$text_variable);

Comment: @Genadinik I know, I've seen your previous question. Nope, the problem is strictly on the insert side.

Comment: Ah ok, but then I am still not clear what I am doing wrong? :))))  I escaped that stuff once and added to db.  Seems pretty straight forward, right?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Genadinik there is some code in your application that does escaping too. You have to find it.

Comment: Ah yes, you were right - there was a very hidden second escape :))))))  thank you - you are the jedi master of this :)

Comment: @Col he didn't say data came from browser but you solved it, good diagnosis

Answer (score 1):

Always use [prepared statements](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm) to interpolate data into SQL.  Then you don't have to do any escaping at all.

Answer (score -1):

$sql = "insert into my_table (numeric_id, string_value) values ('$some_number' , '$some_text')";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

/**
just use (") instead of (');
*/

Answer (score -2):

First of all, escape your input:

```
$sql = 'insert into my_table ( numeric_id , string_value ) values (' . mysql_real_escape_string($some_number) . ', "' . mysql_real_escape_string($some_text) . '")';
```

Second, the issue with the slash is likely due to PHP Magic Quotes. You can read more about that here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

You can check if magic quotes is turned on by running this:

```
var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());
```

If it's on, you could either disable it (if you have access to php.ini) or you can use PHP code to fix the problem that magic quotes creates:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
    array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
```

(taken from PHP.net)

Comment: escape not "input" but strings only. magic quotes cannot be cause they do not escape \r\n

Comment: @Col how do you know he's cast the numeric value to int? You're very militant with your downvotes.

Comment: @Andy that's third overescaping question in last 10 min. 2 of them have already accepted wrong answers. I am just afraid for this one. Indeed afraid.

Comment: Really... 2 downvotes? @Col, am I missing something here or are you keeping the correct answer to yourself?

Comment: @Andy look, it's like a flood! Numerous wrong answers! Doesn't it scare you too?

Answer (score -4):

this should work

```
$sql = "insert into my_table ( numeric_id , string_value ) 
        values ( '.$some_number.' , '".$some_text."' )";
```

Comment: What's the reason for this code to work better than in the opening post?