# Getting rid of \r\n

Tags: php, textarea, newline

I'm printing out text from a database and I keep getting **\r\n** and I'm not completely sure why. This is how my code looks like

```
form action="portal.php" method="post" class="label-top">
    <div>
       <label for="name">News Message</span></label>
        <form method="post" action="" name="bio">
         <textarea name="bio" cols="25" rows="5">


             <?php echo stripslashes($_SESSION['bio']) ?> 


     </textarea><br>
```

I'm trying to use stripslashes but it's not working

I would like my text to be printed out like this

```
Test
Test
```

But instead it goes like this

```
Test\r\nTest
```

**EDIT**

After following you guys everything seemed to go fine until I publish it.
I think there's something wrong with my POST method

If anyone has the time to go over this that'd be greatly appreciated.

```
  <?php
include("mysql_connect.php");
session_start();


if( $_SESSION['login'] != 1 ) {
header( 'Location:login.php' ) ;}


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bio']);
$user_input = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET bio ='$bio' WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' ");
$_SESSION['bio'] = $bio;
    } 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST2') {
$bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notification']);
$user_input = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET notification ='$notification' WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]' ");
$_SESSION['notification'] = $notifiation;
    } 

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
        <title>APPSTARME</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="login.php">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="APPSTARME" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
    <article>

<h2 class="underline">Logged in as  <?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['username']); ?>  </span></h2>

            <form action="portal.php" method="post" class="label-top">
                <div>
                     <label for="name">News Message</span></label>
                     <form method="post" action="" name="bio">
<textarea name="bio" cols="25" rows="5">

<?php
 echo nl2br($_SESSION['bio']); ?> 
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Update Message" /></form>
                </div>
```

Comment: i'm worried about how you are checking your requests.. instead of your conditionals checking REQUEST_METHOD, use the $_POST global array.  Also, you shouldn't stray away from HTTP.  Use POST, and use a conditional in there. don't create another method named POST2

Comment: When I log in everything looks alright but when I update it with the post method everything goes back to the \r\n\ issue

Answer (score 6):

You need `nl2br($_SESSION['bio'])`

**EDIT:**

Since you should print the text inside `<textarea>`, try this one:

```
preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'&#13;',$_SESSION['bio']')
```

`&#13;` is [Carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

Comment: I concede. Forgot about this one.

Comment: a `<br/>` inside a textarea will render as `<br/>` and will not cause a line break. http://jsfiddle.net/SkDHd/

Answer (score 1):

`stripslashes` does not remove `\r\n`

You need: `preg_replace('~\r?\n~','<br/>', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php 
$string = "Hello\r\nWorld\r\n!\r\n"; 
$string = nl2br($string); 
echo $string;
?>
```

Good luck.

*I recomend to give a look in to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449580/replacing-r-n-with-php) post for more info about your problem.*