# MySQL PHP statements is returning junk data included with the records

Tags: php, mysql

Lately my newly created tables in a MySQL database are returning "**\r\n\r\n\r\n**" on my SELECT statements along with the stored data. I don't know where this junk data is coming from because it is not visible in phpMyAdmin. It is happening only in newly created tables, it doesn't happen in old ones.

I used phpMyAdmin to create the table, but here is the exact statement to create it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_analysis` (
  `project_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uGroupId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_address` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_strengths` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `user_weaknesses` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table information is this:

```
Type: InnoDB
Collation: utf8_general_ci
```

Here is the query I'm making:

```
$query = "SELECT user_strengths FROM user_analysis WHERE `project_ID` = ? AND `uGroupId` = ?";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $this->pID, $this->gID);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($strengths);
            $stmt->fetch();
            echo $strengths;
        }
```

I also tried not using prepared statements and hard coding the query, but it still returns junk data. I tried like this:

```
$query = "SELECT user_strengths FROM user_analysis WHERE `project_ID` = '10256' AND `uGroupId` = '10'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "User strengths: " . $row["user_strengths"];
}
```

I used the answer found here as a temporary fix: [Replacing \r\n with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449580/replacing-r-n-with-php)

But working around it is not the problem. The problem is that this shouldn't happen to begin with. What could be causing MySQL to return this junk data? Again, the junk data is not visible from phpMyAdmin. I also tried inserting data directly from phpMyAdmin and carefully make sure there was no such thing as "**\r\n\r\n\r\n**" in what I inserted, but it still returns that junk data along with the records.

Any ideas?

Comment: You keep saying "returning junk data"...Tell us exactly what is being returned. \r\n are new lines, and normally shouldn't be seen.

Comment: This is not a database issue. To see what is happening, try putting values directly in your variables and inspect them later on. For example, try this: `echo 'Hello' . PHP_EOL . 'World';` <- you shouldn't see `\r\n` there.

Comment: Along with the data that is stored, it is returning \r\n\r\n\r\n at the beginning of the data. It is visible because when I console.log the JSON.stringified data, it appears there. For example: If a record said: "Some user address" it returns "\r\n\r\n\r\n Some user address" and if I make a JSON encode of all the columns it returns something like this when stringified: {"\r\n\r\n\r\n user_address:\""\Some user address\", "\user_strengths\":"\some data\", "\user_weaknesses\":"\some data\","\"\"} and those slashes and newlines mess everything up when I go to the javascript and try to use it.

Comment: @Christian: Hi. Yes, the newlines characters don't appear when printed like that, however, the newlines are still there and they were never inserted by me in the database. The problem is that if I JSON encode that data, I cannot access it as an object in javascript, because the newlines and slashes mess everything.

Comment: @g_l Probably, your problem is that you have some PHP scripts that are either outputting newlines *or* end with a `?>` and a bunch of newlines after that.

Comment: The point of all is that the database is returning newlines and slashes that don't exist. It shouldn't return things that don't exist.

Comment: @Christian: Hmmm. Makes sense. After all the other pages of the webpage that use old tables don't do that. I'll check on that right now. Thanks.

Comment: @g_l I'm pretty sure the database is not at fault.

Comment: @Christian: Yes, the database wasn't at fault. Neither the PHP. In javascript I was stringifying the resultant data that was already stringified. json_encode() stringifies the data so there was no need for me to do it already. By applying a JSON.stringify() over the json_encode(), that junk data that I'm viewing appears. Anyway, I couldn't have found the error had it not been for what you told me about something wrong with my php scripts which led me to also re-write the ajax code in order to test. Thank you very much. Your help was much appreciated.