# Can't get rid of /r/n

Tags: php, string, replace

I explored all the previous questions and solutions, nut none of them works in my situation.

I have an input text area where accepts employee ids. End users could use comma , enter, space to separate multiple employee ids, and I need to change any separation into commas.

This is my code:

```
$emplids = preg_replace('/[,\t\n\r\s]+/',",",$emplids);
```

And then, I need to only keep the numbers and commas:

```
$emplids = preg_replace("/[^X0-9,]/", "", $emplids);
```

And then I need to store them into anarray:

```
$emplids = explode(",", $emplids);
```

Now only the end users put comma among employee ids could work, line breaks could not work.

I tried double quotas:

```
$emplids = preg_replace("/[,\t\n\r\s]+/",",",$emplids);
```

It doesn't work neither.

It seems like a tiny question, but it really takes me hours. And any hints is highly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing \r\n with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449580/replacing-r-n-with-php)

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of `\r\n` or `\n\r`?

Comment: should be /r/n, I will have a try!

Comment: light, I tried preg_replace("/[,\r\n]+/",",",$emplids) just now. It dosn't work.

Comment: Did you try to use `trim($emplids)` ?

Comment: don't very understand, but trim only removes side characters, right? I need to remove inside ones.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just get all the ids with the rule that one id can only contain digits, nothing else.

```
$input = <<<EOF
123 356 353,255
2424,535 35
EOF;

preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here since it'd be ugly in a comment:

```
php > $x = '\n'; // single quotes
php > $y = "\n"; // double quotes
php > var_dump($x, $y);
string(2) "\n"
string(1) "
"
```

Note the difference in quoting styles, and the quotes' effect on what PHP sees as being in the string: `'`-quoted strings do not understand any `\` escapes, EXCEPT for `\'` and `\\`. Any other escaped char in a `'`-quoted string is simply a backslash followed by that character.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to preg_replace('/[,\\r\\n]+/',",",$emplids) . No working.

Comment: preg_replace("/[,\r\n]+/",",",$emplids) . NO working neither. :-( Trying others...

Comment: I really realize it is the quoting issue. Thank you so much! Will report any progress.

Comment: you need to show an example of your input text. we can't help with a regex unless we know what it's going to be applied to.

Comment: change \ to \' with ' ', and it works! Other ways don't work. :-) Thank you Marc B! I should have included the input examples. It is 12345/r/n67890

Comment: I mean, change \ to \'  within  ' ' :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the real reason.

I included a script where uses clean function:

```
if($_POST) {
        $_POST = clean($_POST);
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST,1) . "</pre>";

    }
```

And in my script, 
$emplids = $_POST['emplids']; 
.....
$emplids = explode(",",preg_replace("/[^X0-9,]/", "", preg_replace('/[,\t\n]+/',",",$emplids)));

If remove the clean function, the single ' ' and / within them work well together!