# Function for removal of newline and carriage return is not working

Tags: php

I have tried many following possible but still not working.

Following all the possibilities for removing \r\n\r\n from data. **None of them is working**

```
$data = strtr($data, array(
              "\r\n" => "",
              "\r" => "",
              "\n" => "",
              "\t" => " "));

$data = str_replace(array("\r","\n","\r\n"), '', $data);

$data = preg_replace("\r\n", '', $data);

$data = preg_replace(array("\r","\n","\r\n"), '', $data);

$data = preg_replace("~[\r\n]+~", '', $data);

$data = trim(preg_replace(array("\r","\n"), '', $data));

$data = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $data));
```

And the **var_dump($data)** is the data contins some html decoration tags

```
    array(3) { ["flag"]=> string(7) "success" ["data"]=> array(3) { ["data"]=> array(3) { [108955]=> array(15) { ["pkgname"]=> string(0) "" ["name"]=> string(28) "SI - Mundome - Win iPhone 6s" ["preview_url"]=> string(32) "http://m.sk.mevida.me/wap/9766/?" ["type"]=> string(5) "other" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> NULL ["offer_description"]=> string(972) "

æ— æ ‡é¢˜æ–‡æ¡£

All banners , Text, bridge pages must be approved in advance. No words like "free" or "you have won".

User Conversion Flow: MO Flow with Click2SMS:

1.User clicks on the banner

2.User fill into his SMS application

3.User clicks on the confirmation button.

4.User's service request is received.

GEO: Slovenia

Device:All Device

Carriers:All carrier

Caps:NO

Push Notification traffic allowed:Yes

Incentivized Traffic allowed:NO

Email Traffic allowed:Yes

Adult traffic allowed:NO

Search traffic allowed:Yes

SMS Traffic allowed:NO

Wifi traffic allowed:Yes
" ["category"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "Sweepstakes Subscription" } ["tracklink"]=> string(63) "http://global.ymtracking.com/trace?offer_id=108955&aff_id=22097" ["countries"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "SI" } ["payout"]=> string(5) "6.500" ["platform"]=> array(38) { [0]=> string(7) "Desktop" [1]=> string(3) "iOS" [2]=> string(7) "Android" [3]=> string(17) "BlackBerry Tablet" [4]=> string(5) "MeeGo" [5]=> string(10) "BlackBerry" [6]=> string(7) "Unknown" [7]=> string(5) "Linux" [8]=> string(4) "Bada" [9]=> string(13) "Windows Phone" [10]=> string(7) "Symbian" [11]=> string(14) "Windows Mobile" [12]=> string(16) "PlayStation Vita" [13]=> string(12) "Nintendo Wii" [14]=> string(5) "Nokia" [15]=> string(10) "Windows RT" [16]=> string(9) "Series 40" [17]=> string(11) "Playstation" [18]=> string(3) "SGP" [19]=> string(11) "MTK/Nucleus" [20]=> string(5) "Maemo" [21]=> string(3) "PSP" [22]=> string(4) "Java" [23]=> string(9) "Windows 8" [24]=> string(4) "Palm" [25]=> string(6) "Danger" [26]=> string(5) "webOS" [27]=> string(12) "Nintendo DSi" [28]=> string(7) "Windows" [29]=> string(12) "Nintendo 3DS" [30]=> string(4) "Brew" [31]=> string(3) "MMP" [32]=> string(4) "MIDP" [33]=> string(6) "Aliyun" [34]=> string(12) "Windowsphone" [35]=> string(7) "Samsung" [36]=> string(7) "Brew MP" [37]=> string(7) "Firefox" } ["traffic"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(21) "Email Traffic allowed" [1]=> string(22) "Search traffic allowed" [2]=> string(20) "Wifi traffic allowed" [3]=> string(33) "Push Notification traffic allowed" } ["creative_link"]=> array(0) { } ["remaining_daily_cap"]=> int(-1) } [108956]=> array(15) { ["pkgname"]=> string(21) "il.co.dominos.android" ["name"]=> string(60) "App Download - Domino\'s Pizza - Android(IL) - Non incentive" ["preview_url"]=> string(67) "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=il.co.dominos.android" ["type"]=> string(7) "android" ["title"]=> string(23) "×“×•×ž×™× ×•×¡ ×¤×™×¦×”" ["description"]=> string(2274) "×× ×—× ×• ×ž×–×ž×™× ×™× ××•×ª×š ×œ×”×•×¨×™×“ ×‘×—×™× × ×•×œ×™×”× ×•×ª ×¢×•×“ ×”×™×•× ×ž××¤×œ×™×§×¦×™×™×ª ×”×–×ž× ×•×ª ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×”×ž×”×™×¨×”, ×”×ž×”× ×” ×•×”×—×›×ž×” ×‘×™×•×ª×¨ ×‘×¢×•×œ×!××– ×ž×” ×”×›× ×• ×œ×›× ×‘××¤×œ×™×§×¦×™×” ×”×œ×•×”×˜×ª ×©×œ× ×• â€“Â· ONE CLICK PIZZA - ×“×•×ž×™× ×•'×¡ ×¤×™×¦×” ×ž×©×™×§×” ×©×™×¨×•×ª ×˜×›× ×•×œ×•×’×™ ×—×“×©× ×™ × ×•×¡×£ ×©×œ ×‘×“×¨×š ×œ×”×–×ž× ×ª ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×”×ž×”×™×¨×” ×‘×¢×•×œ×! ×ž×”×™×•× × ×•×›×œ ×‘×œ×—×™×¦×ª ×›×¤×ª×•×¨ ××—×ª ×œ×”×˜×¢×™×Ÿ ×”×–×ž× ×ª ×¤×™×¦×” ×‘×¤×—×•×ª ×ž×—×ž×© ×©× ×™×•×ª ×•×ª×•×š ×¤×—×•×ª ×ž×—×¦×™ ×©×¢×” ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×›×‘×¨ ×ª×“×¤×•×§ ××¦×œ×›× ×‘×“×œ×ª ×—×ž×” ×•×˜×¢×™×ž×”. ×”×—×œ ×ž×”×™×•×, ×›×œ ×œ×§×•×— ×“×•×ž×™× ×•'×¡, ×©×”×–×ž×™×Ÿ ×‘×¢×‘×¨ ×ž×”×¨×©×ª, ×™×•×›×œ ×‘×œ×—×™×¦×ª ×›×¤×ª×•×¨ ××—×ª (×ž××¤×œ×™×§×¦×™×™×ª ×”×ž×•×‘×™×™×œ, ××• ×ž×”××ª×¨ ×©×œ ×”×—×‘×¨×”) ×œ×”×˜×¢×™×Ÿ ×‘×©× ×™×•×ª ×‘×•×“×“×•×ª ××ª ×”×”×–×ž× ×” ×”×§×‘×•×¢×” ×©×œ×• ×”×—×œ ×ž×”×›×ª×•×‘×ª ×œ×ž×©×œ×•×— ×•×¢×“ ××ž×¦×¢×™ ×”×ª×©×œ×•×. ×›×¤×ª×•×¨ ×”- ONE CLICK PIZZA ×ž×¦×™×¢ ×’× ××¤×©×¨×•×™×•×ª ×‘×—×™×¨×” ×ž×”×™×¨×•×ª ×‘××ž×¦×¢×•×ª ×¡×œ×™×™×“×¨ ×‘×™×Ÿ ×”××•×¤×¦×™×•×ª ×”×©×›×™×—×•×ª ×‘×™×•×ª×¨ ×‘×©×“×•×ª ×”×©×•× ×™×, ×›×š ×‘×©× ×™×™×” × ×™×ª×Ÿ ×œ×‘×—×•×¨ ×‘×™×Ÿ ×©×ª×™ ×›×ª×•×‘×•×ª ×ž×’×•×¨×™×, ××• ×›×ž×•×‘×Ÿ ×‘×™×Ÿ ×©×ª×™ ×¤×™×¦×•×ª ×ž×¢×•×“×¤×•×ª. Â§ ×”×¨×›×‘×ª ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×”××”×•×‘×” ×¢×œ×™×š- ×‘×¢×–×¨×ª ×”- Pizza builder, ××©×£ ×”×¨×›×‘×ª ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×”×ž×ª×§×“× ×‘×™×§×•×, ×”×›×™ ×§×œ ×œ×”×¨×›×™×‘ ××ª ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×”×ž×•×©×œ×ž×ª ×‘×©×‘×™×œ×š: ×œ×‘×—×•×¨ ×¡×•×’ ×‘×¦×§, ×œ×—×œ×§ ××ª ×”×ª×•×¡×¤×•×ª ×œ×—×¦××™× ××• ×¨×‘×¢×™× (××¤×©×¨ ×œ×©×™× ×ª×•×¡×¤×ª ×©×•× ×” ×¢×œ ×›×œ ×¨×‘×¢ ×•×–×” × ×—×©×‘ ×œ×ª×•×¡×¤×ª ××—×ª!) ×•×¢×•×“ ×ž×œ× ××¤×©×¨×•×™×•×ª ××—×¨×•×ª.Â§ ××™×¤×” ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×©×œ×™- ×¨×•×¦×” ×œ×“×¢×ª ×ž×” ×§×•×¨×” ×¢× ×”×¤×™×¦×” ×©×œ×š ×‘×›×œ ×¨×’×¢? ××™×Ÿ ×‘×¢×™×”! Domino's Tracker ×”×•× ×¤×™×ª×•×— ×‘×œ×¢×“×™ ×•×¡×•×¤×¨ ×ž×ª×§×“× ××©×¨ ×ž××¤×©×¨ ×œ×›× ×œ×¢×§×•×‘ ×‘×–×ž×Ÿ ××ž×ª ××—×¨×™ ×”×”×–×ž× ×” ×©×œ×š ×‘×›×œ ×©×œ×‘, ×ž×¨×’×¢ ×©×”×ª×§×‘×œ×” ×‘×¡× ×™×£ ×•×¢×“ ×©×”×©×œ×™×— ××¦×œ×š ×‘×“×œ×ª.×‘×ª××‘×•×Ÿ!×× ×™×© ×œ×š ×©××œ×•×ª ××• ×”×¢×¨×•×ª ×‘× ×•×’×¢ ×œ××¤×œ×™×§×¦×™×”, ×× ×—× ×• ×ª×ž×™×“ ×©×ž×—×™× ×œ×¢×ž×•×“ ×œ×¨×©×•×ª×š ×‘×›×ª×•×‘×ª× ×• android@dominos.co.il" ["offer_description"]=> string(1163) "

Restrictions

Own Creative, Video Creatives, APK, Redirect traffic cannot be used.

No invalid or duplicate leads

All banners and bridge pages should be approved in advance.

User Conversion Flow:

1. User is directly redirected on Google Play to download the application

2. User has to open the application

GEO: Israel

Device: Android

Carrier: All

Cap: 400 leads per day

Push Notification traffic allowed: Yes

Incentivized traffic allowed: No

Search traffic allowed: Yes

Adult traffic allowed: No

Email traffic allowed: Yes

SMS traffic allowed: Yes

Wifi traffic allowed: Yes

Facebook traffic allowed: Yes

In App Traffic allowed(APP): Yes




" ["category"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "App Download-Android" } ["tracklink"]=> string(63) "http://global.ymtracking.com/trace?offer_id=108956&aff_id=22097" ["countries"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "IL" } ["payout"]=> string(5) "0.680" ["platform"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Android" } ["traffic"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(21) "Email Traffic allowed" [1]=> string(22) "Search traffic allowed" [2]=> string(19) "SMS Traffic allowed" [3]=> string(20) "Wifi traffic allowed" [4]=> string(33) "Push Notification traffic allowed" [5]=> string(32) "In - App Display traffic allowed" [6]=> string(24) "Facebook traffic allowed" } ["creative_link"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(81) "http://uploads.yeahmobi.com/offer_file/thumb_e90b2203193e7dcf48ff234d8c50e585.zip" } ["remaining_daily_cap"]=> int(392) } [108957]=> array(15) { ["pkgname"]=> string(0) "" ["name"]=> string(30) "MY - Snacpchat - Celcom & Digi" ["preview_url"]=> string(73) "http://adsplatform.com/ads/?adsid=938e08930da59143d3296955fde269c4&e=1912" ["type"]=> string(5) "other" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> NULL ["offer_description"]=> string(661) "

æ— æ ‡é¢˜æ–‡æ¡£

All banners and bridge pages should be approved in advance. No prelanders!!!

One Click Flow: Single-Optin

GEO: MY

Device: All

Carrier:Celcom & Digi

Push Notification traffic allowed: Yes

Incentivized traffic allowed: No

Adult traffic allowed: Yes

Wifi traffic allowed: Yes

Search traffic allowed: Yes

display traffic allowed: Yes
" ["category"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "Entertainment Subscription" } ["tracklink"]=> string(63) "http://global.ymtracking.com/trace?offer_id=108957&aff_id=22097" ["countries"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "MY" } ["payout"]=> string(5) "2.500" ["platform"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "Desktop" } ["traffic"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(21) "Adult traffic allowed" [1]=> string(22) "Search traffic allowed" [2]=> string(20) "Wifi traffic allowed" [3]=> string(33) "Push Notification traffic allowed" [4]=> string(23) "Display traffic allowed" } ["creative_link"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(81) "http://uploads.yeahmobi.com/offer_file/thumb_21ffc6a2782ffe160a0a183eb25c6e49.ZIP" } ["remaining_daily_cap"]=> int(-1) } } ["totalrecord"]=> int(4028) ["totalpage"]=> int(1343) } ["msg"]=> string(8) "success." }
```

Comment: What`s the line ending of this script?

Comment: I tried also $data = str_replace("\r\n",'', $data ); **not working**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove new lines from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

Comment: @halayem anis :- i first checked that only as that have voted more times . but still **not working**

Comment: @RohanKhude Show us your data (`var_dump($data);`), and *not working* is useless unless you get: `PHP warning code is not working on line 3`

Comment: Give us the exact output of `var_dump($data);` from your source code.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` and `\r` are escape characters that are only escaped when you use them in a double-quoted string.there is a big difference between `'\r\n'` and `"\r\n"`

`'\r\n'` will result in a four character string containing a slash, an `'r'`, another slash and an `'n'`, whereas `"\r\n"` will contain two characters, those being the new line and carriage return characters.

```
    //$text in string format
    $text = str_replace("\r\n",'', $text);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449580/replacing-r-n-with-php

i visited this link as you visited. I also tried from that but its **not working.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` with `\R` special character, it will replace all occurences of new lines and it is cross-platform.

```
preg_replace( '/\R+/', '', $string );
```

Comment: @RohanKhude, then is something wrong with your string, maybe you have **HTML entities** inside and not new lines.

Comment: it contains html decoration tags as well as new line and carriage returns